# text wrap issue with Safari on iOS iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, safari

I have got a browser specific design issue with Safari iOS (using ipad). phone icon which I placed in the label field for that menu, **bumps up to a second line.** It is working fine other browser.

[image]

I tried with white-space:nowrap CSS. but that doesn’t work. So I am not sure if this is a wrap problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you share the css code for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have realized. Safari will auto-detect any phone numbers on a web page and turn them into links.

In the `<head>` of your web pages, add:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```